# Excel Interop - Display full screen error?

Tags: excel, vb.net, interop

I'm using Excel Introp for a .net application to embed an Excel workbook in a windows userform.

```
        excApp.Visible = False
        wb = excApp.Workbooks.Open(directOpenPath) ' , [ReadOnly]:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
        wb.Saved = True  ' necessary to prevent Excel has stopped working error and to not actually do a save 

        hwnd1 = CType(excApp.Hwnd, IntPtr)
        SetParent(excApp.Hwnd, pnlExcel.Handle)
        SendMessage(excApp.Hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0)
        MoveWindow(hwnd1, 0, 0, pnlExcel.Width, pnlExcel.Height, True)
        excApp.Visible = True
```

There are ActiveX buttons on the worksheet that work fine when I open using the above code.

However, it is my desire to make the object look less like Excel so I wanted to hide the ribbon, formula bar, etc.

I added the line:  excApp.DisplayFullScreen=True. Upon doing that, clicking on a button no longer kicked off the associated macro.  Additionally, I could no longer click on any cell in the worksheet.   This seems like odd behavior but I have traced it down to the DisplayFullScreen line.

Also I am trying to include the following:

```
excApp.ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
excApp.ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
excApp.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
```

But I get a object not set to reference error.  If I add excApp.ActiveWindow.Activate, the worksheet "locks up" again and I can't click on any cells. 
Any ideas?